# Global variable in C changes in spite of not making any changes to it

Tags: c, pointers, floating-point, stack, global-variables

Please see my code below. I am confused as to why the value of my global variable called, 'magicnunmber' changes after the first 'iteration', though I am not changing it's value anywhere in code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

float m[4][4] = { {0,0.5,1,0},{0.33,0,0,0.5},{0.33,0,0,0.5},{0.33,0.5,0,0} };
float v[4][1] = {{0.25},{0.25},{0.25},{0.25}};
float vdash[4][1];
int i =0, j=0;
int r1,c1,r2,c2,k;
float magicnumber = 0.01;
int iteration = 0;

int main(void)
{
 r1 = c1 = r2 = 4;
 c2 = 1;

 //while(1)
 while(iteration < 5)
 {
  printf("magicnumber==[%f]\n",magicnumber);
  //magicnumber = 0.01;
  iteration++;
  printf("\n---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");

  for(i=0;i<r1;i++)
  { 
   for(j=0;j<c2;j++)
   {
    vdash[i][j] = 0;
    for(k=0;k<c1;k++)
    {
     vdash[i][j] = vdash[i][j] + (m[i][k] * v[k][j]);
    }
   }
  }

  if(myfun(vdash,v)==0)
  {
   break;
  }
  else
  {
   printf("\n");
   for(i=0;i<r1;i++)
   {
    v[i][1] = vdash[i][1];
   }
  }
 }

 return 0;
}

int myfun(float* vdash, float* v)
{ 
 float delta = 0;

 for(i=0;i<r1;i++)
 {
  delta = (*(vdash+i) - *(v+i));
  (delta < 0)?(delta = delta*-1):delta;

  if( delta > magicnumber)
  {
   return 1;
  }
 }
 return 0;
}
```

My output

```
magicnumber==[0.010000]

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

magicnumber==[0.000000]

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

magicnumber==[0.000000]

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

magicnumber==[0.000000]

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

magicnumber==[0.000000]

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have tried it out on gdb, but all I can see is that the value changes to a very small number when it enters a new iteration.

```
1: magicnumber = 0.00999999978
1: magicnumber = 0.00999999978
1: magicnumber = 5.60519386e-45
```

How can `magicnumber` change if I never assign anything to it?

Comment: The compiler doesn't know the dimensions of array `vdash` and array `v` when cast to `float*` and passed to function `myfun`. Since these arrays are global, you may as well refrain from passing them to the function to begin with. That said, you should strive to refrain from using global variables where possible (which is pretty much **everywhere** in your given code). BTW, I would expect the compiler to warn you about the dimensions issue on the line containing `myfun(vdash,v)`. Does it not???

Comment: Because you are clobbering your memory in myfun()  This should not compile without some warning/error due to the mismatch of the function parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The actual error that is happening is in the line `v[i][1] = vdash[i][1];`. Here your array is of consists of 1 column and you are referring to the second column of the array, hence you are writing beyond your array which is leading to undefined behavior, which is causing this problem.

So change the line `v[i][1] = vdash[i][1];` to `v[i][0] = vdash[i][0];`

Also your code is terribly written. If you want to use a 1-D array then why to define it like `arr[length][1]` when you can use `arr[length]`. This can prevent you from such mistakes which you just did. Your myfun function is also terrible. Have a look at the below code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
//Try not to use global variable. Global variables are bad :D.
int main(void)
{
 float m[4][4] = { {0,0.5,1,0},{0.33,0,0,0.5},{0.33,0,0,0.5},{0.33,0.5,0,0} };
 float v[4] = {0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25};
 float vdash[4];
 int i =0, j=0;
 int r1,c1,r2,c2,k;
 float magicnumber = 0.01;
 int iteration = 0;
 r1 = c1 = r2 = 4;
 c2 = 1;

 //while(1)
 while(iteration < 5)
 {
  printf("magicnumber==[%f]\n",magicnumber);
  //magicnumber = 0.01;
  iteration++;
  printf("\n---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");

  for(i=0;i<r1;i++)
  { 
//   for(j=0;j<c2;j++) --since you are only going through j once. also it is not required in this code
//   {
    vdash[i] = 0;
    for(k=0;k<c1;k++)
    {
     vdash[i] = vdash[i] + (m[i][k] * v[k]);
    }
//   }
  }

  if(myfun(vdash,v,magicnumber,r1)==0)
  {
   break;
  }
  else
  {
   printf("\n");
   for(i=0;i<r1;i++)
   {
    v[i] = vdash[i];
   }
  }
 }

 return 0;
}

int myfun(float vdash[], float v[], int magicnumber, int r1)
{ 
 float delta = 0;
 int i;
 for(i=0;i<r1;i++)
 {
  delta = (vdash[i] - v[i]);
  (delta < 0)?(delta = delta*-1):delta;

  if( delta > magicnumber)
  {
   return 1;
  }
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: The problem is writing beyond the end of the array causes **undefined behavior**. None of the values are guaranteed after you inject it into your program. Your program may continue to run, run with corrupted values, or segfault. The results are simply **undefined**.